# How to get div to remain fixated until jquery actiavtes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar inside a header which snaps to the top of the screen once you scroll over 100px downwards. The functionality is fine but I would like the navigation bar to remain fixed on the right until the snap, so essentially, the navigation bar needs to remain in a fixed position until you scroll past 100px..

Please visit http://www.justletmeusethisnameplz.co.nf/index%20stacky.html to see my website.

Thanks

Here is the relevant HTML

```
<div class="header"> <!-- BEGINNING OF HEADER -->

    <div id="logo"> <!-- BEGINNING OF LOGO -->

    <h1 class="sliding-middle-out">Hi</h1>

    </div> <!-- END OF LOGO -->

    <div id="navigation">  <!-- BEGINNING OF NAVIGATION -->

    <div style="float:right"> <!-- BEGINNING OF IDK -->

    <div id="slider"></div>
    <a href="index.html"><div id="one" class="item"><div class="inside">Home</div></div></a>
    <a href="about.html"><div id="two" class="item"><div class="inside">About Us</div></div></a>
    <a href="content.html"><div id="three" class="item"><div class="inside">Content</div></div></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><div id="four" class="item"><div class="inside">Contact</div></div></a>

    </div> <!-- END OF IDK -->

    </div> <!-- END OF NAVIGATION -->

    </div> <!-- END OF HEADER -->
```

Here is the relevant CSS

```
.header{
        height:100px;
        width:960px; 
        float:left;
        background-color:white;
      }
      #navigation{
        height:40px;
        font-size:20px;
        color:black;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        float:right;
        background-color:white;
        padding-top:5px;
        position:relative;
      }
      #navigation.stick{
        height:40px;
        font-size:20px;
        color:black;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        float:left;
        background-color:white;
        padding-top:5px;
        position:fixed;
      }
      .logo{
        height:100px;
        width:425px; 
        float:left;
      }
```

Here is the relevant JavaScript/ JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 1){
    $('#navigation').addClass("stick");
    }else{
    $('#navigation').removeClass("stick");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're inserting 4 jquery-sources, any reason for this?

Comment: Idk really, i thought I needed it but I have been told many times I don't but if I remove it I don't think some aspects would work :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you'd like the stick class to be applied once you've scrolled 100px down the page, in which case you need to change the javascript:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    $('#navigation').toggleClass('stick', $(document).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```

Comment: Sorry but no, my current code does that. I would like the navigation bar to remain in a fixed position until I have scrolled down a hundred pixels. All I thought I needed to do was change the original #navigation class to have position:fixed but when I did that it was fix until 100pixels like I wanted but it was fixed on the left hand side over the logo

Comment: Your current code triggers the class after 1px, not 100px. `$(document).scrollTop() > 1`

Comment: Yes sorry I know that, I haven't updated it on my server yet but I will do it now. But thats not the issue

Comment: "I would like the navigation bar to remain in a fixed position until I have scrolled down a hundred pixels." I don't know what else you are asking?

Comment: I made the update. Ok sorry it is hard to convey. If you go to the web page I provided the link for earlier, scroll down ever so slowly using the scroll bar not the mouse, you will see the navigation bar disappear as per normal until you reach 100px where it snaps on. I would like it to follow you all the way down as you scroll (so remain fixed) until it reaches 100pixels in which it snaps into the centre instead

Comment: Do you understand that better?

Comment: So like, the nav bar should be visible for the entire 100pixels of scrolling, it should be fixed on the right, until it reaches 100 pixels where it is still visible but snaps into the centre instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:fixed` to your header class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's funny! I was seriously expecting it not to work but it KIND OF did. It did work but it only stayed fixed on the right for about 30 pixels and then snapped, it definitely didn't snap at 100 pixels like it was supposed to. It snapped early.???

Comment: Are you talking about logo?

Comment: No I don't care about logo. The navigation bar, it needs to remain on the right hand side, and still be fixed until I reach 100 pixels. Right now, it's not fixed, it scrolls under below with the rest of the content

Comment: ok - follow couple of steps..1.) Make your header as  `position:fixed` and when you scroll down beyond 100 px remove position from header and make div under navigation class as `float:left`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the navigation bar in place you need to modify `#navigation`:

```
#navigation {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

then change javascript in this way:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#logo").height()-$("#navigation").height()){       
        $('#navigation').addClass("stick");
    }else{
        $('#navigation').removeClass("stick");
    }
});
```

That condition also prevents the navigation bar to bleed out of the header, or you can keep your current code, if you prefer.